# PostgreSQL: Drawbacks for large wal_keep_segments?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I would like to keep at least 12 hours worth of wal segments around to keep replication going for extended network outages (namely long DR tests that my database is not a part of)
I've estimated that I will need to raise my wal_keep_segments from 64 to 1000+

Are there any drawbacks of doing this other than the space it would require? i.e. performance?
I'm considering the archive option as a backup plan for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the disk space, there is no problem with a high `wal_keep_segments` setting.